# Lots of difficulty integrating jquery-file-uploader with carrierwave in my rails app

Tags: carrierwave, jquery-file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.0

I've been stuck on this issue for hours now, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Essentially I am allowing users to upload a video, and therefore want a progress bar to show how long the upload is taking.

When the form is submitted, the video successfully uploads. However, jquery does nothing to the progress bar to show the upload is taking place.

The javascript is below. Edit_User is the class of the form to be submitted.

```
$(function () {
$('.edit_user').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data){
        data.submit();
    },
    progress: function (e, data){
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
     },
   });
 });
```

Here is my form:

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :video %><br>
 <%= f.file_field :video %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :video_cache %>
 </div>
<div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%; height:10px"></div></div>
   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Continue" %>
  </div>
```

I know that the javascript can access the form, because I can get the javascript to state 'uploading...' when a user has chosen a form to upload for example, but I cannot get the progress bar to show progress, or to do other things like state "upload complete".

EDIT: Ok so I managed to get it working with a bit of CSS, but it seems to upload with unlikely speed. I uploaded a 23MB file and the progress bar went to about 100% in 2 seconds. What is jquery-file-uploader using as its measure of whether the file is uploaded?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on your computer, and uploading to your computer, that's definitely a reasonable amount of time.

You can check the developer tools on your browser, and see how long it's measuring the upload as taking. In Chrome, right click on the page, select "inspect" and then go to the Network tab. Now, when you upload the file, you should see the browser measuring the timing as well.

(I know it's possible on IE and Safari, but I don't know those browsers well enough to tell you how. You may need to install something to access these tools on those browsers)